# How to get view attribute in activity?

Tags: android, user-interface

I hope get view's attributes after view is inflated, but all sof questions need AttributeSet, is there way to do it without AttributeSet?

for ex:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/open_with" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
           android:text="open"
           android:layout_width="30dp"
           android:scaleX="1.2"
           android:scaleY="1.2"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_open_in_new_black_48dp"
           android:layout_height="30dp"/>
```

I hope get "scaleX" with following:

```
getAttr(View v, attrName)
```

how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get most of the attribute values from View class's method

```
yourImageView.getText();
yourImageView.getScaleX();
```

The complete methods reference can be found from the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Comment: I need a common way to get attribute value, it's not only "scaleX", some view attribute cannot get value with `getMeth`